# Como obter uma rota infinita no Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

Eu tenho duas urls:

- http://you.axitech.com.br/busca/qualquercoisa
- http://you.axitech.com.br/busca/qualquercoisa/outracoisa

E estou tendo usar estes routes:

- $route['busca/(:any)'] = "Busca/index/$1";
- $route['busca/(:any)/(:num)'] = "Busca/index/$2/$";

Eu gostaria de usar uma url infinita mas não consigo o resultado desejado. Alguém pode me dar um help? Quando eu acesso a primeira url, funciona corretamente porém a segunda url não funciona. O que eu preciso está representado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Então, eu estava vendo aqui e o **$_POST** está indo corretamente mas não está entrando no index, ou seja, se eu tento sobrescrever e eliminar o **/index** dá erro. Resumindo, acho que o erro está no roteamento mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Busca/index/$2/$ me parece mero erro de digitação. nâo seria só por o $(numerodoparametro) corretamente em todos os casos? $1/$2/$3 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar:

```
$route['busca/(:any)'] = "Busca/index/$1";
$route['busca/(:any)/(:num)'] = "Busca/index/$1/$2";
```

Assim você acessará:

http://www.seusite.com.br/busca/qualquercoisa/umnumero

E ele poderá ser processado assim:

```
public function index($palavra, $numero = false){

}
```

Para você fazer rotas infinitas como você disse, você acabará gerando erros, pois como você não sabe o que está sendo passado na URL e quando, então seria díficil.

Você terá que criar as rotas de acordo com os parâmetros que serão recebidos.

Comment: É, basicamente o que eu comentei na pergunta. não postei como resposta pq não é solução pro "infinito" que foi pedido (apesar de eu concordar que não faz sentido ser infinito se de qq forma vai ter que saber como lidar com os parâmetros).